# MS Access vba query where

Tags: vba

Simple Question.
For example, i have a Customer that have 10 Orders and each order include 6-10 Items.

i want to create a vba query that will desplay all the items of a specific customer.

My query is:

```
x = CustomerNum
Query = "Select OrderNum from CustomerOrderT Where CustomerNum = " & x
Set result = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Query)

y = result!OrderNum
'(there is a lot of orders on y)

Query = "Select Product From OrderProducts Where OrderNum = " & y
Set result = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Query)
```

The problem is that i only see the Products of the first order and i cannot see the products of all the orders that i select on the first query.
Need some help to handke this situation.
**Thank you very much.**

Comment: that is because you only get the first order, you need to loop through the returned record set and get each order number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just execute a single query for all orders:

```
x = CustomerNum
Query = "  SELECT CustomerOrderT.CustomerNum, " & _
                  CustomerOrderT.OrderNum, " & _
        "         OrderProducts.Product " & _
        "    FROM CustomerOrderT INNER JOIN OrderProducts " & _
               ON CustomerOrderT.OrderNum = OrderProducts.OrderNum " & _
        "   WHERE (((CustomerOrderT.CustomerNum)=" & x & ")) " & _
        "ORDER BY CustomerOrderT.OrderNum, " & _
        "         OrderProducts.Product;"
```

And then loop over all the records, noting each change in `OrderNum`

But beware of building SQL like this if you don't control how variable `CustomerNum` is assigned, as you open yourself to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Excel VBA code has almost no security at all so SQL injection attacks can't be avoided, VBA even password protected can be easily accessed/hacked. So one shouldn't use it if there are concerns about security.

Comment: On the contrary, it doesn't matter whether the code is VBA or whether the VBA project is locked, if you're executing custom-built SQL against a database, but you allow a user to enter a malicious SQL-snippet in a cell or InputBox, and that snippet ends up being inserted into a SQL string, then you have major issues.

Comment: I know, but in excel VBA it is almost impossible to avoid a malicious user to hack SQL string as (s)he can easily modify the code. The only solution to that is to login into database with limited permissions. Then you don't need to care about SQL injection either, because injecting will just return an error.

Comment: Or force client-access to use Stored Procedures

Comment: @caiohamamura in Excel VBA you would be using the ADODB API/library, which completely supports parameterized queries, as does DAO which Access uses. Also with Windows Authentication to the database server there's no need to store credentials anywhere, be it in code or in some connection file. Bad code is on the programmer, not the language.

Comment: That said if you're worried about users (...colleagues??) modifying the code to malicious intent, you have worse problems than SQL injection.

Comment: That's my point. The problem of SQL injection is for user to input something like `1 GO DROP TABLE AnyTable GO`. If you trust the users which will have access to the workbook you probably should not care about them inserting such things in the filter cell or input box.